# XCode - iOS - <OCMock/OCMock.h> file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, ocmock

I Have an iOS application that I am trying to add OCMock to in order to better unit test it.  I've followed the instruction on ocmock.org as well as instructions I've found in other places but still I cannot get my test code to compile.

Here's what I've done

Added the source code to my project directory
[image]

Create the groups in my project to mimic my file system
[image]

I selected the option to add to my test targets so the framework was added appropriately as well as the Library Search Path
[image]
[image]

Then I manually added the headers to the Header Search Path
[image]

And added the -ObjC linker flag 
[image]

Then when I go to import the header file, I get the file not found error
[image]

Any ideas what I am missing here???

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have the search path `test/libraries/OCMock`. Then you have `#import <OCMock/OCMock.h>`.

This fails because there is no file `test/libraries/OCMock/OCMock/OCMock.h`.

You use the search path `test/libraries`, or you can create a prefix directory to hold `OCMock` and have the search path point at that.

I generally have a directory with the library name and version number before the actually directory.

The directory `test/libraries/OCMock-X.X.X` could contain the `OCMock` directory. That way the search path still be more specific: `test/libraries/OCMock-X.X.X` and you still use `OCMock/OCMock.h` as the include.

Comment: Thank you so much!  That was it!  I wasted so much time on this today.

As for the directory with the version number, do you usually but the lib in there too?

Comment: I try to keep the original packaging of the library. So yes, I think it would be `test/libraries/OCMock-X.X.X/libOCMock.a`

Answer (score 0):

One more thing to check, for anyone else having this problem - I copied OCMock from one project to another and everything *looked* right, but it wasn't finding the include file.  It turned out that even though I had the right groups in Xcode, the files had all been dumped into one directory.  I needed to create folders on disk and associate them with the groups in Xcode.  The accepted answer here clued me in to what was wrong (though as is often the case, in hindsight it should have been obvious).